# Request-promise constantly saying it's a success when the link I've requested to crawl doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry if this sounds silly, I couldn't think of a better title - feel free to suggest.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
const fs = require('fs');
var moment = require('moment');
var date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:sSS a');

var status;

var proxyCheck = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://googleeeukss',
    proxy: 'http://localhost',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3107.4 Safari/537.36'
    }
}

console.log("test");

rp(proxyCheck)
    .then(function (htmlString) {
        // Process html...
        status = "working";
        console.log("link works");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Crawling failed...
        status = "bad"
        console.log("bad");
    });
```

This is my code, so see the url "http://googleeeukss" doesn't exist, yet it's still coming to the .then and saying it does exist.

Does anyone have any idea why it's saying it works when it doesn't? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm attempting to learn node by taking up projects but I'm stuck on this at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is my output: `$:jstest me$ node test.js 
test
bad`. If obviously fails.

Comment: I wonder why mine succeeds, my output is     test
link works

Comment: Restarted my node and it worked, that was weird lol. Thank you @DeadEye

Comment: Aye you sure you get a true "Server not found" and you are not facing a DNS hijacking (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking)?